# Selecting max from join of 2 tables in sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite, union

I need a small help with selecting a max value of a column of two tables. When I run the sql statement below, I get maximum from both tables, ie 2 rows. How can I get the maximum of both of them (SQLITE 3)?

> Select max(transid) from tbltrans union select max(transid) from
>   tbltrans2

Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing the `union` first is one way:

```
select max(transid)
from (select transid from tbltrans union all
      select transid from tbltrans2
     ) t
```